# Java DerbyDB: How can I get all the tables of a database one by one and in ascending order by the date they were created?

Tags: java, database, date, derby

I have an application where I need to create a new table every three or so days. Each table will have some information.

After a month or some time I may decide to run some statistics on all the tables of the database that I've created initially in order to find out some results.

The statistics however will show how the data changed throughout the days. So let's suppose on day one we created the first table with name "date_1"

On day three "date_3", on day six "date_6", on day nine "date_9" and on day twelve "date_12". In reality the numbers after the "date_" string will be real dates, also I may create another table after two or one days not necessarily three.

Now suppose on day 13 I decide to run the statistics. One way to find out the available tables inside a database is to run the following code:

```
  public void printTables(){

    static Connection conn;
    String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true";
   try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet resultSet = dbmd.getTables(null, null, null,
                new String[] { "TABLE" });
        int tableCount = 0;
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
            tableCount++;
        }
       }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Now the thing is, the following code returns the tables in alphabetical order, which means that as a result we will get the following tables printed:

```
 date_1
 date_12
 date_3
 date_6
 date_9
```

However I need them in the following order

```
 date_1
 date_3
 date_6
 date_9
 date_12
```

So if I get the table names in the second order, I could simply run the appropriate select statements for each table returned, do the statistics and print the correct results. So my question is, is it possible to get the tables in ascending order by the date they were created and not simply by their name(String)?

Comment: this might be achieved more easily by using Derby system tables.  i don't have a Derby DB at hand to give you the exact SQL.

Comment: thanks I will look into it. For now I will assume that the tables have the name of dates(for instance 29_9_2012) and then every time I run the statistics I will save all the table names inside an array list of Dates by transforming each name(String) to the appropriate Date object. Then I will sort the ArrayList using a Comparator. Sounds like a naive solution but for a start I think it's OK.

Comment: @ksm001: your specialized comparator and Arrays.Sort() sounds like a fine technique to me.